# Why does nautilus look different on XFCE than other distributions?

Tags: nautilus, xfce, lxde

[image: Back: nautilus on LXDE. Front: nautilus on XFCE.]

*Back window: nautilus on **LXDE**. Front window: nautilus on **XFCE**.*

Why does nautilus look different on XFCE than other distributions?

For example notice that **Home** is selected in both windows above. On the right window (**XFCE**) it is smaller than on the left. And the icons are different.

Is there a way to make nautilus look exactly similar to how it looks on **XFCE**? (I'm already using the **XFCE** default icon theme on LXDE, but it didn't cut it).

Comment: A different GTK theme being used? What's so surprising about that?

Comment: they look the same to me (same options; eg. home on both & in same position (below recent & above desktop)).  as for appearance - that's largely theme & window-manager options chosen.  LXDE & XFCE differ in how they present things, especially if one theme uses GTK+2 and another uses a GTK+3 theme.  to make them look the same; use the same themes & same wm/dm  (lxde I think uses openbox...)

Comment: Thank you both. Oh I see, so it's probably because it's using GTK+2..

Answer (score 1):

The theme name is *Greybird*. I finally managed to find it. It can be even be set up on gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different GTK theme, if you want to change the look of it just change the GTK theme.

> XFCE themes are available at xfce-look.org. Xfwm themes are stored in /usr/share/themes/xfce4, and set in Settings > Window Manager. GTK+ themes are set in Settings > Appearance.

Comment: How do you change the theme please? And can you use the same one as in XFCE?

Comment: Settings > Appearance. or read my edited answer